# Centering social media icons

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, icons, frontend

Trying to center my social media icons horizontally and collapse them vertically when the screen size changes. Any tips or suggestions as to what I can apply to the css to accomplish that? There's currently no css applied to the icons below.. thanks!!!

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="page-footer">
            <p style="font-family: 'Buena-Park-JF', serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-size: 40px; text-align: center;"> Find Us!</p>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:50px"></i>
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px;">facebook</i>
            <i class="material-icons "style="font-size:50px">map</i>
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:50px">phone</i>
        
            
            

              </div>
    </footer> 



.footer {
padding-top: 60px;
background-color: #000;
color:#eae2d8;}

.page-footer{
width: 100%;
padding: 50px 0px 70px 0px;
background-color: $basic-dark-color;}
```

Comment: Your are welcome to stackoverflow community ^_^ ,  in order to help you, can you put the css code here.

Comment: @AziMez, just added the css.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take all of the `i` tags. 
Surround them with a `div` class.
Then, add this inside the tag after div: `style="display:flex;justify-content:center;"`
It should work as you narrow the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
I add two CSS element "**container**"  and "**i**"

```css
container {
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;

        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;

        flex-wrap: wrap;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;

        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

i {

    border: 3px solid yellow;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    
}

.footer {

padding-top: 60px;
 
background-color: #000;
color:#eae2d8;
}

.page-footer{
width: 100%;
padding: 50px 0px 70px 0px;
background-color: $basic-dark-color;



}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<footer class="footer">
        <div class="page-footer">
            <p style="font-family: 'Buena-Park-JF', serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-size: 40px; text-align: center;"> Find Us!</p>
            
          
          <container>  
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:50px"></i>
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px;">facebook</i>
            <i class="material-icons "style="font-size:50px">map</i>
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:50px">phone</i>
     </container>
        
            
            

              </div>
    </footer> 


</body>
</html>
```